# Change dataframe index values while keeping other column data same

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 4 columns and 251 rows and an index that is a progression of numbers e.g. 1000 to 1250 . The index was initially necessary to aid in joining data from 4 different dataframes. However, once i get the 4 columns together, i would like to change the index to a number progression from 250 to 0. This is because i would be performing the same operation on different sets of data (in groups of 4) that would have different indices, e.g. 2000 to 2250 or 500 to 750, but would all have the same number of rows. 250 to 0 is a way of unifying these data sets, but i can't figure out how to do this. i.e. i'm looking for something that replaces any existing index with the function range(250, 0, -1)

I've tried using set_index below and a whole bunch of other attempts that invariably return errors,

```
df.set_index(range(250, 0, -1), inplace=True)
```

and in the instance when i am able to set the index of the df to the range, the data in the 4 columns change to NaN since they have no data that matches the new index. I apologize if this is rudimentary, but i'm a week old in the world of python/pandas, haven't programmed in +10yrs, and have taken 2 days to try to figure this out for myself as an exercise, but its time to cry... Uncle!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try introducing the 250:0 indices as a column first, then setting them as the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('abcdefghij'), 'col2': range(0, 50, 5)})
df['new_index'] = range(30, 20, -1)
df.set_index('new_index')
```

Before:

```
  col1  col2  new_index
0    a     0         30
1    b     5         29
2    c    10         28
3    d    15         27
4    e    20         26
5    f    25         25
6    g    30         24
7    h    35         23
8    i    40         22
9    j    45         21
```

After:

```
          col1  col2
new_index           
30           a     0
29           b     5
28           c    10
27           d    15
26           e    20
25           f    25
24           g    30
23           h    35
22           i    40
21           j    45
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I just tried it, and i believe i'm getting a datatype conflict of some sort. I am able to add 250:0 as a column to the dataset, the set_index command doesn't throw any errors, but when i look at the dataframe, i still have the old index with the 250:0 as the last column. Below is the output i got on executing the set_index command

Comment: I didn't use the `inplace=True` argument in my code like you did, so it doesn't actually modify `df`, just returns a new dataframe with those indexes set. Add that argument, or assign the result to a new variable, and you should be good.

Comment: All solved. Thanks and sorry for my incomplete response earlier.

Answer (score 6):

You can just do

```
df.index = range(250, 0, -1)
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: Yep, this answer is better, because it avoids creating the extra column before setting the index.